# how to create dynamic fields on the basis of user select dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I am trying to do is in my below code when I am select the dropdown list value then the dynamic field is open like text filed select field etc. And when I change the dropdown list value then the new field is open like upload file field text field etc. but in my below code is not working.

How can we do that using HTML CSS JavaScript jQuery?

```js
function addElement() {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("name", "newInput");
    var foo = document.getElementById("newAdd");
    foo.appendChild(element);
}
function addInput(){
    document.getElementById("newAdd").innerHTML="";
     var noInp=parseInt(document.getElementById("formName9").value);
        while(noInp>0)
        {
        addElement();
            noInp--;
        }           
    }
```

```html
<select id="formName9" name="blockUnits" onchange="return addInput()">
 
 <option value="">select field</option>
 <option value="4">apple four field</option>
 <option value="2">banana two filed</option>
 <option value="6">grapes six field</option>
 <option value="1">apple 1 field</option>
 <option value="4">guava four field</option>
 <option value="8">lichi eight field</option>
</select>
<form>
<div id="newAdd"> </div>.
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think you should have `return` in your onchange attribute.

Comment: what do you mean by `apple four field` ? add 4 field ?

Comment: @Swati yes i want to make when i click on apple four field then 4 filed is show and when i am click on banana two field then 2 field is show like that  how can we do that ??

Comment: try this code https://jsfiddle.net/2ez3wt17/1/ seems your getting the string value from the select

Comment: so `value="apple"` change to `value="4"` and then same for others .

Comment: @Zaza i want when i select apple four field then 4 different filed is show like text field select field upload filed and search filed how can we do ?? right now in here https://jsfiddle.net/2ez3wt17/ when i select apple 4 field then all four text filed is show,but i want all four field is different

Comment: @Swati i want when i select apple 4 field then four diff. field is show. But right its only all four text field is show

Comment: @praveenakumari In your code you can do it for different fields. seems you only creating the input field and your code is not based on your question. Kindly post the question clearly then only community people look to answer your question

Comment: @praveenakumari try this code it may give you some idea to creating a random fields https://jsfiddle.net/2ez3wt17/6/. if your want specific option have specific fields your can pass the option and generate by your own

Comment: @zara thanks but i want random fixed field means when i am select apple four field then four diff. option is there 2 is text field and 2 is search and when i am select banana 2 field then 2 diff. field is there 1 is upload and 1 is input text and when i am select apple 1 field then 1 dropdown field is show like that.  is it possible this type functionality we can do ??

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("formName9").value` is not a number. you should add `.length` to return the number of characters in a string.

```
  var noInp=parseInt(document.getElementById("formName9").value.length);
```

Comment: var noInp=parseInt(document.getElementById("formName9").value.length); not work